# How to find intersection of two tangent lines in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, intersection

I have two points(x1,y1 and x2,y2) on a circle and the center (c1,c2) of a circle
and need javascript code to calcuate the intersection point of two tangent lines thru points x1,y1 and x2,y2.

I am using it to convert from a circle (really an arc defined by the above points) to a quadratic bezier curve.

Comment: You can get the linear equation of each (circleOrigin, point) lines. Then you can get the linear equation of the tangente. Then with the two linear equations, you can get the intersection coordinates. This is only trigonometry (and btw, I'm not english, so sorry if I don't use the exact words)

Comment: Are you using a canvas to draw the circle or are you just working with numbers rather then images.

Comment: There is no trigonometry needed to find the equation for a tangent line. It is the perpendicular of the radius.

Answer (score 3):

The normals of the tangents are:

```
n1x = x1 - c1
n1y = y1 - c2
n2x = x2 - c1
n2y = y2 - c2
```

Using the following parameters:

```
d1 = n1x * x1 + n1y * y1
d2 = n2x * x2 + n2y * y2
```

the equations of the tangents can be written as:

```
x * n1x + y * n1y = d1
x * n2x + y * n2y = d2
```

Solving the linear equation system yields the following result in general case:

```
x = (d2 * n1y - d1 * n2y) / (n1y * n2x - n1x * n2y)
y = (d1 * n2x - d2 * n1x) / (n1y * n2x - n1x * n2y)
```

In javascript:

```
var x1,y1,x2,y2,c1,c2; // inputs
var x, y;              // outputs

... get the parameters somehow

var n1x = x1 - c1;
var n1y = y1 - c2;
var n2x = x2 - c1;
var n2y = y2 - c2;
var d1 = n1x * x1 + n1y * y1;
var d2 = n2x * x2 + n2y * y2;

var det = n1y * n2x - n1x * n2y;
if (det === 0) {
    // The lines are parallel
} else {
    x = (d2 * n1y - d1 * n2y) / det;
    y = (d1 * n2x - d2 * n1x) / det;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  this is just what I was looking for.  I will give it a try.   I guess I should have used cx,cy instead of c1,c2 but you seemed to have understood anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The vector from the center `(c₁, c₂)` to a point `(xᵢ, yᵢ)` on a circumference is `(xᵢ-c₁, yᵢ-c₂)`.

That means the line through `(c₁, c₂)` and `(xᵢ, yᵢ)` has slope `sᵢ = (yᵢ-c₂)/(xᵢ-c₁)`.

Let `tᵢ` be the slope of the tangent line on `(xᵢ, yᵢ)`. `tᵢ = -1/sᵢ = (c₁-xᵢ)/(yᵢ-c₂)`.

Let `oᵢ = yᵢ-tᵢxᵢ`. Then the tangent line through `(xᵢ, yᵢ)` is

```
y = tᵢ(x-xᵢ) + yᵢ = tᵢx + oᵢ
```

Doing this for `i = 1, i = 2` produces a linear equation system.

```
y = t₁x + o₁
y = t₂x + o₂
```

Solving it gives the intersection of the tangent lines

```
    o₁-o₂
x = ─────
    t₂-t₁

       o₁-o₂
y = t₁ ───── + o₁
       t₂-t₁
```